# Python - Group command in nested list

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, nested

I have a 2D numpy array containing a set of data imported from a file by *loadtxt*. The first column contains the x array, any further column contains y values for different parameters. I want to fit the data and combine the fitparameters in a new 2D array. Here the fit results of the first set of data should act as initial parameter to fit the next set of data. Therefore I use a for loop to sweep through the columns of the array.

```
fitparam=zeros((0,3),float)
init_vals=[a,b,c]
for ii in arange(1,data.shape[1]):
    popt,pcov=curve_fit(func,data[:,0],data[:,ii],p0=init_vals)
    init_vals=popt
    fitparam=concatenate((fitparam,resize(popt,(1,3))),axis=0)
```

Is there a more suitable way to do this, using a for example a nested list? Thereby I can avoid the creation of the array *fitparam* and the *concatenate* command.
Something like:

```
init_vals=[a,b,c]
fitparam=array([
    popt,pcov=curve_fit(func,data[:,0],data[:,ii],p0=init_vals)
    init_vals=popt
    array([popt[0],pcov[0,0],popt[1],pcov[1,1],popt[2],pcov[2,2]])
    for ii in arange(1,data.shape[1])
)]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could initialize an empty array with `data.shape[1] - 1` rows to store your fitted parameters, then fill in the rows one-by-one as you process the data:

```
fitparam = empty((data.shape[1] - 1, 3), float)
init_vals = [a, b, c]

for ii in arange(1, data.shape[1]):
    popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, data[:,0], data[:,ii], p0=init_vals)
    init_vals = popt
    fitparam[ii - 1] = popt
```

This avoids the expensive array concatenation step.

If you don't want to store the previous fitted parameter values then all you need to do is keep hold of the most recent set of parameters to pass in as `p0=` for the next loop iteration:

```
popt = [a, b, c]

for ii in arange(1, data.shape[1]):
    popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, data[:,0], data[:,ii], p0=popt)
```

Comment: Thanks it is better but I thought I can avoid the for loop. I like the idea behind a nested list. I thought I can put in as "first" argument a group of comments   which will be interpreted during each iteration. In my case the fit procedure, the delivery of the fitparamters and the output of the parameters.

Comment: There's no way to avoid having some sort of loop, since the initialization parameters for each iteration depend on the result of the previous iteration. On the other hand, your code will probably spend almost all of its time doing the fitting, so it's unlikely that the loop will add any noticeable performance overhead. I think this is a case of premature optimization.